# PDOStatement::fetchAll() :SQLSTATE[HY000]:

Tags: php, pdo

This error return to me when I executed the code

> Warning: PDOStatement::fetchAll() [pdostatement.fetchall]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: Extraneous additional parameters in C:\AppServ\www\cms_project\lib\database_model.class.php on line 28
>
> Warning: array_shift() [function.array-shift]: The argument should be an array in C:\AppServ\www\cms_project\lib\database_model.class.php on line 34
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\cms_project\lib\cat.class.php on line 43

this is database_model class:

```
<?php

class database_model
{
public function attribute()
{
$string = array();
foreach($this->db_feild as $feild){

if(is_int($this->$feild) || is_double($this->$feild)){
$string[] = $feild . " = ".$this->$feild."";

}else{
$string[] = $feild ." = '".$this->$feild ."'";
}
}
return implode(', ',$string); // convert array to string
}



public static function read($sql, $type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,$class = null)
{

global $db_connect;
$resualt= $db_connect->query($sql); // query from db
if($resualt){
if(null !== $class && $type == PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
$data = $resualt->fetchAll($type,$class);

}else{
$data = $resualt->fetchAll($type);
}
if(count($data)== 1){
$data = array_shift($data); // array_shift  علشان نطلع من الارارى
}
return $data;
}else{
return false;
}

}


private function add()
{
global $db_connect; // to use the conection to database

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->table_name . " SET " .$this->attribute();

$affectedrows = $db_connect->exec($sql); // to include to database
if($affectedrows != false){
$this->id = $db_connect->lastInsertId();
}else{
return false;
}
return true;
}


private function update()
{
global $db_connect;
$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->table_name . " SET " .$this->attribute()
."WHERE id = ".$this->id;
$affectedrows = $db_connect->exec($sql);
return $affectedrows != false ? true : false;

}



public function delete()
{
global $db_connect;
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$this->table_name."WHERE id = ".$this->id;
$affectedrows = $db_connect->exec($sql);
return $affectedrows != false ? true : false;

} 



public function save()
{
return ($this->id === null)? $this->add():$this->update();
}
}
?>
```

this is cat class :

```
class cat extends database_model
{
public $id; 
public $user_id;
public $created;
public $title;
public $slug;
public $content;

public $table_name = 'cat';

public $db_feild = array(
'user_id',
'created',
'title',
'slug',
'content',

);

public static function control()
{
// __CLASS__ ==> RETURN THE THIS CLASS 
$all_categries = self::read("SELECT * FROM cat ",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,__CLASS__);

$table = '<table class="cpanel_cat">';
$table .= '<tr>
<th># </th>
<th>category name </th>
<th colspan="2"> control </th>
'  ;
if($all_categries !== false){
if(is_object($all_categries)){
$table .= '<tr>
<td>1 </td>
<td>'. $all_categries->title .'</td>
<td><a href="" >EDIT</a> | <a href="" > Delete</a> </td>
';    
}else{
$i = 1;
foreach($all_categries as $cat)
$table .= '<tr>
<td>'.$i++ .' </td>
<td>'.$cat->title .'</td>
<td><a href="" >EDIT</a> | <a href="" > Delete</a> </td>
';    
}
}else{
$table .= '<tr><td colspan="4">sorry categroy not found !!</td></tr>';
}
$table .='</table>';
return $table; 
}

}
```

Comment: Since your code is unreadable, go to line 43 like the error tells you and check what you tried to treat as an array. Since it's not an array, deal with it from there (find out what type it is etc.). On another note - what you coded there is completely useless since you have PDO that does exactly what you tried to map. Bottom line - you created a layer that does nothing, and now you can't even debug it.

Comment: You're doing `if($all_categries !== false)`, and then in the `else` you have `foreach($all_categries as $cat)`.  You can't `foreach` over `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The error `General error: Extraneous additional parameters` comes from the following lines:

```
$type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
$class = __CLASS__
$data = $resualt->fetchAll($type,$class);
```

If you are trying to fetch a record from the database as a class by passing a classname: 
`$type` should be `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

When `fetchAll()` fails it is not returning an array causing the `array_shift()` and `foreach()` the fail as well.